# Simple Gender Guesser

Tags: php, object-oriented

I have made a simple gender guesser for an app and thought that this simple bit of code may be useful to other developers. It takes in a string and returns an 'f' for Female and an 'f' Male depending on the name provided. I am not a PHP expert so I was wondering if anyone can give me some feedback on this code.

The full code can be found at the repository [here](https://github.com/anthonybudd/Gender/tree/18980a9a1725b5579422ba0cae2372651e611f57)

```
<?php

Class Gender{
    public $gender;
    protected $maleNames    = [];
    protected $femaleNames  = [];
    public $isMale      = FALSE;
    public $isFemale    = FALSE;
    public function __construct($name, $default, $unknown, $custom){
        $this->maleNames    = $this->getMaleNames($custom);
        $this->femaleNames  = $this->getFemaleNames($custom);
        $this->gender       = $default;
        if(in_array($this->getName($name), $this->maleNames)){
            $this->isMale = TRUE;
        }
        if(in_array($this->getName($name), $this->femaleNames)){
            $this->isFemale = TRUE;
        }
        if($this->isMale && !$this->isFemale){
            $this->gender = 'm';
        }elseif(!$this->isMale && $this->isFemale){
            $this->gender = 'f';
        }elseif($this->isMale && $this->isFemale){  
            $this->gender = $default;
        }else{
            $this->gender = $unknown;
        }
    }
    public static function guess($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []){
        $g = new Self($name, $default, $unknown, $custom);
        return $g->gender;
    }
    public static function isMale($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []){
        $g = new Self($name, $default, $unknown, $custom);
        return ($g->gender === 'm')? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
    public static function isFemale($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []){
        $g = new Self($name, $default, $unknown, $custom);
        return ($g->gender === 'f')? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
    protected function getName($name){
        $name = explode(' ', $name);
        $name = $name[0];
        $name = strtolower($name);
        return $name;
    }
    protected function getMaleNames($custom){
        $names = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/names/male.json'));

        if(is_array($custom['male'])){
            foreach($custom['male'] as $name){
                $names[] = strtolower($name);
            }
        }
        return $names;
    }
    protected function getFemaleNames($custom){
        $names = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/names/female.json'));

        if(is_array($custom['female'])){
            foreach($custom['female'] as $name){
                $names[] = strtolower($name);
            }
        }
        return $names;
    }
}

echo Gender::guess('anthony');

?>
```

Comment: First up: if your files contain nothing but PHP code, it's recommended to _omit_ the closing `?>` tag: _"If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file."_ [see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) for details

Answer (score 1):

**Performance aspects regarding file access**

In your `getMaleNames($custom)` function you **first** load the `/names/male.json` contents, **then** look at `$custom` and use this one if not empty: so in the latter case you spent time reading file while it's useless. You'd instead look at `$custom` first, then at file if needed.
Obviously the same applies to `getFemaleNames()`.

In the other hand, when you call one of your static functions you create a new `Gender` instance, so invoking both of the `get...Names()` functions, which ends with reading two files for each external call as soon as they don't provide non empty `$custom` argument. 
It could be far more efficient to create a unique instance once, then use its contents.
As a first thought this might be achieved by looking at the `Gender` instance from the static functions, and create it only when it doesn't exist yet. *But look also at the strategy part below.*

**Compacting code**

There are several places where this can be done.

The best example is in the already cited `get...Names()` functions: they can be simply factorized like this (also includes the change suggested about files):

```
protected function getNames($gender, $custom) {
  if (is_array($custom[$gender])) {
    foreach ($custom[$gender] as $name) {
      $names[] = strtolower($name);
    }
  }
  $names =
    json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/names/' . $gender . '.json'));
  return $names;
}
```

Another example is that, even if you want to keep separate functions available for the external calls (though `guess()` only is probably enough), you can simplify the two `is...()` functions, like this one (same for `isFemale()`):

```
public static function isMale($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []) {
  return self::guess($name, $default, $unknown, $custom) === 'm';
}
```

Finally the `getName()` function can be simplified like this:

```
protected function getName($name) {
  return strtolower(explode(' ', $name)[0]);
}
```

**Strategy**

Analyzing what your class is made for, it appears that creating an instance is not required. The only data which needs to be saved between two external calls is the content of the `/names/...json` files (and only if we retain the first change I proposed above!).

So you might:

- keep properties `$maleNames` and `$femaleNames` only, and make them `static`.
- also make the `protected` functions `static`.
- move all the logics currently in `__construct()` to `guess()` (working with simple variables rather than properties).
- and not have `__construct()` at all.

Additionally observe that, in the current `__construct()` logics:

- the affectation to `$this->gender` is never used further
- `getName()` can be called only once and is very simple, so the function can be abandoned in profit of direct comptuting
- the if/else sequence can be replaced by directs returns

So it ends with this full code simplified version:

```
Class Gender{
  protected static $maleNames;
  protected static $femaleNames;
  public static function guess($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []){
    if (!self::$maleNames) {
      self::$maleNames = self::getNames('male');
    }
    if (!self::$femaleNames) {
      self::$femaleNames = self::getNames('female');
    }
    $name = strtolower(explode(' ', $name)[0];
    $isMale = in_array($name, self::$maleNames);
    $isFemale = in_array($name, self::$femaleNames);
    if ($isMale && !isFemale) {
      return 'm';
    }
    if (!$isMale && isFemale) {
      return 'f';
    }
    if ($isMale && isFemale) {
      return $default;
    }
    return $unknown;
  }
  public static function isMale($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []) {
    return self::guess($name, $default, $unknown, $custom) === 'm';
  }
  public static function isFemale($name, $default = 'm', $unknown = 'm', $custom = []) {
    return self::guess($name, $default, $unknown, $custom) === 'f';
  }
  protected static function getNames($gender, $custom) {
    if (is_array($custom[$gender])) {
      foreach ($custom[$gender] as $name) {
        $names[] = strtolower($name);
      }
    }
    $names =
      json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/names/' . $gender . '.json'));
    return $names;
  }
}
```